# How to convert string array into array and remove empty elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string

I have a string `'["", "abc", "", "def", "", "mno", "", "", "", "", ""]'`. i want to convert it into array and remove empty values from that array. my desired output is `abc;def;mno`.

Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: You can simple do it in one line using JSON.parse(a).reject(&:empty?).join(';')

Comment: Just for your example `string.scan(/\w+/) #=> ["abc", "def", "mno"]` but not really a general solution.

Comment: @max, I don't understand why this is a dup. This question concerns a string; the referenced earlier question concerns an array of strings.

Comment: John, do you mean you want the desired output to be `["abc", "def", "mno"]`?  (`abc;def;mno` is not a Ruby object, which may account for the downvote).  If so, you should edit.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`JSON.parse`](https://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/parse) and [`select`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select) method:

```
str = '["", "abc", "", "def", "", "mno", "", "", "", "", ""]'
arr = JSON.parse(str).select(&:present?)
```

Output array: `["abc", "def", "mno"]`

If you want to get `abc;def;mno`:

```
joined = arr.join(';')
```

Output string: `"abc;def;mno"`

Hope this helps

Comment: for pure ruby can use `arr = JSON.parse(str).reject(&:blank?)`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your string with `JSON#parse` and use `delete` with `join`:

```
str = '["", "abc", "", "def", "", "mno", "", "", "", "", ""]'
JSON.parse(str).tap { |arr| arr.delete('') }.join(';')
# => "abc;def;mno"
```

Comment: but its a string not an array('["", "abc", "", "def", "", "mno", "", "", "", "", ""]'), how can i convert this string into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
str = YAML.load('["", "abc", "", "def", "", "mno", "", "", "", "", ""]')
str.select{|a| a if a != ""}.join(";")
```